# Set headers variable for subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, postman

I have one setup call that returns session id in header as shown below.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json'  'https://<url>/initConn'
```

Returns a session id as part of response header as:

```
{ ...,
 "sessionId": "111",
...
}
```

Now I have to use the same session id in all subsequent call as:

```
 curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-SESSION_ID: 111' 'https://<url>/someCommand'
```

Using postman, how could one:

- extract session id from header
- attach in the subsequent calls in Postman

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you would this through command line using `cURL`, but you can use the `Environment Variables` to set the get the header from one API request, save it and then use it in another API call.

Suppose we have an API, called F1, which gives us a parameter called `uid` in response, and we need to use this `access_token` in our header for another API , called F2

- Go to the `Manage Environments` on the corner end of the Postman window.

[image: Manage Environments]

- Click on `Manage Environment` and in the new window, click on Add to add a new environment

[image]

- Add the new environment variable name that you want to add. Suppose I want my variable to be called `access_token`, so I will add a new key, to the newly added environment and keep the value field empty.
  [image]
- Now click on `ADD`, and go to your Postman window, and enter the API endpoint for API F1, along with any header values that you need to send with the F1. Make sure you select the newly created environment from the environments options shown.

[image]

- Now go to Tests, which is located to the right of the `headers`, and enter the following in the test window as shown below

  `var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", jsonData.uid);`

Now hit `SEND` and wait for the response from F1.

[image]

- Open another tab, enter the API end point for F2, and select the newly created environment that you just created in above steps.

Now, since we want the `uid`  from response of to be a part of the header of our request for F2, we need to add this in our header.

Go to the `header`tab, and enter the `uid` as Key and `{{access_token}}` as the value for this key, as show below.

Now, you are all set to make the request for F2. This will extract `uid` from the first API F1, and pass it as the header for API F2

[image]

Comment: Just curious what are you using to write Jasmine tests? Postman-Jasmine?

Comment: It's [postman-bdd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-bdd), allows you to write BDD style tests, using chai-JS syntax. I used it to write Jasmine style tests and then it worked.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting.

Comment: @ValentinDespa yeah it's a very handy library for testing API response from Postman.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the post-request script (possibly labeled "tests"? I'm not at my computer!) to pull data out of the response and store it in a global variable. Then, in the subsequent request, use the pre-request script to grab it, or reference it directly in the headers with `{{myVariableName}}`.