# Is it possible to set environment variable to point to/store a pointer to a previous call in the collection in order to execute the same using 'eval'

Tags: postman

In a postman collection, I have a get token call which gives me an access token valid for 'x' minutes. 
What I want to do is:
1. take the token using 'getToken' postman call and record the time into 'TokenTime' variable
2. In the pre-requisite scripts for all other calls, check if current time is greater than 'TokenTime' by 'x-2 minutes', and if yes call the 'getToken' postman call again

Will it be possible to store a reference to / complete body of the call in the environment variable to eval it just when required above.

Is there anyway in Postman to conditionally call a previous request during execution of a pre-requisite script.

This is not a duplicate of the suggested question - that is another question for another problem i myself asked a few hours ago - that question is concerned about extracting and populating headers and this one is about storing an entire request reference within envt variable which is clearly a different question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set headers variable for subsequent calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628750/set-headers-variable-for-subsequent-calls)

Comment: @Valentin Despa - No - different question altogether - this is about running a previous rest request from within a collection - the original one was about extracting headers